# How do I extends View and also extends Activity for the same class

Tags: android, android-activity, view, extends

This second Activity is called when a button is pressed in the Main Activity:

```
public class Graphics extends ActionBarActivity {

DrawTheField v;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = new DrawTheField(this);

    setContentView(v);

}
```

This is the Graphics class:

```
public class DrawTheField extends View {

String FILEballpossession = "ballpossession.txt";




public DrawTheField(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}


@Override

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);


// graphics stuff here


    FileInputStream fins = null;
    try {
        fins = openFileInput(FILEballpossession);
        byte[] reader = new byte[fins.available()];
        while (fins.read(reader) != -1) {
            ball_possession = new String(reader);
        }
        if (fins != null) {
            fins.close();
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The file ballpossession.txt was created in the Main Activity java.  The
openFileInput method is available in Activity, but not here in this DrawTheField class which happens to be a View.
How can I "extends View" and also "extends Activity" for this class?

Comment: i suppose you are trying to get something from both super classes at the same time, then you can make your class that extends view as an inner class inside the class that extends activity and pass activity context as an object to your view class

Comment: I guess that is what I am trying to do...I just need to read a file into a string inside the class that is an extended view.

Answer (score 1):

You dont. Java does not support multiple inheritance.

http://javapapers.com/core-java/why-multiple-inheritance-is-not-supported-in-java/

> JAVA omits many rarely used, poorly understood, confusing features of
>   C++ that in our experience bring more grief than beneﬁt. This
>   primarily consists of operator overloading (although it does have
>   method overloading), multiple inheritance, and extensive automatic
>   coercions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your class that extends View as an inner class inside your class that extends Activity or if you want to separate both class files, then pass class that extends activity as an object to your class that your class that extends view .

I also realized that you reading a string , then you also read the file in your activity and just pass the string to view class.